# Angular 2 - Plug in dynamic data from API with parameter to HTML?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm fairly new to Angular 2, and I'm trying to find the best way to pass data to a nested component, call a method (REST API) using that data, and return the result into the parent HTML.

I understand how to pass the data - just use the @Input decorator on a variable in the child component.  That gets the data in.  Now I want to process that data and compute a result.  I can't do that in the constructor of the child component, because in the constructor, the input value has not yet been passed.  So where do I do it? Is there a render event I can use? I arrived at a solution that seems to work very well, I just don't know if I'm breaking some rules or causing issues.

Since I'm using Typescript, I can use setters.  I defined a setter for the input value, so in the setter I can run code to process the data.  Here is my working code:

```js
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import { AppService } from "./../../services/appservice";
import { UserProfileService } from "./../../services/userprofileservice";

@Component({
    selector: "displayname",
    template: "{{displayName}}",
    providers: [AppService, UserProfileService]
})

export class DisplayName {

    public displayName: string;
    private profiler: UserProfileService;

       constructor(private appService: AppService) {
           this.profiler = new UserProfileService(this.appService);
       }

 @Input("login")
    set login(newLogin: string) {
        this.profiler.getUserProfile(newLogin, (profile) => {
            this.displayName = profile ? profile.displayName : newLogin;
        });
    }
}
```

What this code does is take a login name as input, fetch the user's display name, and set the displayName variable to the result.  If the result is null, it just returns the login name.  Using the @Input decorator on the setter works great, I've just never seen it done before in any examples so I don't know if there is a better way.

My HTML code looks like this (simplified for this example):

```html
<tr *ngFor="let user of userList>
  <td><displayname [login]="user.loginName"></displayname></td>
</tr>
```

Another way to ask this question is to back up to my basic use case, which I think must be very common.  How do you dynamically insert data from a REST API into an HTML page?  In this case I want to pass in the login name, and render the Display Name, that is fetched from a REST API.  In this case I don't need any HTML formatting (you can see my template is just a variable, no HTML) - is there a simpler way to do this?  Should I be using an @Output?

Thanks,
Randy

Comment: I think you're looking for [Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html), specifically `OnInit()`. Use constructor just to declare dependencies and `ngOnInit()` to do initialization for your components...

Comment: Yes, you're right, thank you! The OnChanges could also work, but since I don't expect ongoing changes, OnInit works just fine.